# Redirect to my login page instead of the default on c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web, authentication

I am using visual web developer and I am creating my first site.

I set access rules for some pages, however, when I preview the site and I click on those pages instead od redirecting me on the Login page I created it redirects me to the default master page one.

How can I change this setting?

Comment: When do you need to be redirected to the login page? When the user hasn't logged in yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify the below section in your web.config file:

```
<!-- Web.config file -->
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms forms="401kApp" loginUrl="/login.aspx" />
   </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/mycustom/loginpage" defaultUrl="~/Pages/Home.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Modify the the web.config for your desired login url.

You can also specify default url and timeout value.